# Entity Framework unexpected behavior on Save Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I Have two Entities Fisioterapeuta and Paciente, one Fisioterapeuta have * Pacientes.
When a Add a new Fisioterapeuta, its ok.

In the Paciente form i have a DropDownList to select the Fisioterapeuta of the Paciente, so, the entity Paciente have a property of type Fisioterapeuta.

When a add one patient, EF duplicates (creates another one) Fisioterapeuta.

I know this occurs becouse the Paciente.Fisioterapeuta is != null, as i using a generic repository when a try to save the Paciente, the Fisioterapeuta goes togheter.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior? how to handle this?

PS: I'am using generic repository, so i cant override SaveChanges or do validations on save.

### Edit1

folowing @Brad Christie sugestion i do the following:

```
Paciente p = (Paciente)grdEdicao.DataContext; //here the DataContext brings me the Fisioterapeuta on the property p.Fisioterapeuta

p.Fisioterapeuta = Repository<Fisioterapeuta>.GetByID((int)comboFisioterapeutas.SelectedValue); // i try to set the Fisioterapeuta getting it from the repository.
```

This change doesnt solve my problem.

### Edit2

I created a github project to test it, here is https://github.com/Ewerton/RelatedEntities_EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i will anwser my own question (i dont like to do this).

I ended up with the following opinion, if i am working with EF, i have have two approaches, as follows:

### NOT using the Referential constraint

In this case, when designing your entities in EDMX simply select the association from tool box, click in the parent entity, drag the line to the child entity and the association will be created, in this way, probaly you will need to take care about attached and detached entities (and if you are using generic repository, like me, you will end with same problem descibed in my question).
With this approach you will write code like this.

```
        Fisioterapeuta f2 = new Fisioterapeuta();
        using (var ctx = new Model1Container())
        {
            f2 = ctx.Set<Fisioterapeuta>().FirstOrDefault();
        }

        Paciente p = new Paciente();
        p.Nome = "Paciente1";
        p.Fisioterapeuta = f2; // here you associate a Fisioterapeuta to a Paciente
```

When you try to Save the "p" entity, the "f2" entity will be created in the database too. One way to avoid it is to manage the state of the "f2" entity taking care about if it is attached or detached.

### USING the Referential constraint

In this case, when designing your entities in the EDMX, instead of select the association in tool box, click in the blank area of EDMX, add new association, fill the form and dont forget to mark the option "Add foreign key property to 'YourEntity' entity". In this way, my entity Paciente will have the FisioterapeutaId property that is a foreign key to Fisioterapeuta, and i can write code like this

```
        Fisioterapeuta f2 = new Fisioterapeuta();
        using (var ctx = new Model1Container())
        {
            f2 = ctx.Set<Fisioterapeuta>().FirstOrDefault();
        }

        Paciente p = new Paciente();
        p.Nome = "Paciente1";
        //HERE ARE THE TRICK. I MANAGE THE ID OF THE RELATED ENTITIE, I DONT LET THIS WORK FOR EF.
        p.FisioterapeutaId = f2.Id;
```

Note that this way i only set the FisioterapeutaId of the "p" object. In this case, when i save the "p" object the Fisioterapeuta entity will not be created again.

### Conclusion

Dont exist the correct way to do it, you need to choose your way by yourself.

PS: I updated the project in GitHub here is the link https://github.com/Ewerton/RelatedEntities_EF

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're re-creating the `Medic` on insert (instead of assigning it a previously established `Medic`) so EF thinks it needs to create a new entry to satisfy the insert.

Make sure that when you assign `Patient.Medic` a reference to a `Medic` already in the database. e.g.

```
patient.Medic = Medics.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name = medicName);
```

*Assuming `medicName` is a value passed from the drop-down. Alternatively (and probably better) you should reference the medic's ID and use that to fetch the reference.*

So, all together:

```
<label for="name">
  Patient Name:
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
</label>
<label for="medic">
  Medic:
  <select id="medic" name="medic">
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
    <option value="1">Dr. Smith</option>
    <option value="2">Dr. Jones</option>
  </select>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Then:

```
Patient patient = new Patient {
  Name = name,
  Medic = Medics.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == medic)
};
```

Comment: i try it, and it not works, i do the following. Patient p = (Patient)grdEdicao.DataContext; //here the DataContext brings me the Medic on the property p.Medic, and tryied to retrieve the patient p.Medic =  Repository<Medic>.GetByID((int)comboMedics.SelectedValue);

Comment: @Ewerton: Can you edit your question to include that code portion? (Makes it a little easier to read while showing others what you've already tried).

Comment: i updated my question and the project in git hub, the solution form me is the use of referential constraints. I do some modifications in the entities name, so, your answer is outdated, sorry :)